# Table header alignment with sorting Image

Tags: html, css, xhtml, web, css-float

This might sound weird, but I have tried all sorts of method to correct this.. :-(

There is a table with header text and sorting images. Some cases the text size is huge, How would I right align and vertical align the image even if the text wraps to 3 lines... I could think only of a table solution, the other jsfiddle link example doesnt work with IE 7, Can somebody guide me on how to achieve this ??

http://jsfiddle.net/4TqRe/8/ (Link)

Thanks :-)

Comment: A way to go around this is using JS to force the position of the arrows. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @makram saleh so? Did this fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/4TqRe/28/

The explenation is quite simple.
Once you put the image (with float right) after the text you simply tell the browser "first parse the text, then behind that float the image right". Quick solution is to put the image infront of the text with a float right. This way the broswer will parse it like "ok, lets float the image right. now parse the text and there is room on the left, so lets put it top left"

Sounds logical?
Hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Yup... But i was thinking without using any additional columns, using a span or something.. still couldn't achieve it :-(